# Why can the .exe file under the Release folder be used to debug in VC++?

Tags: windows, debugging, visual-c++, release

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 to develop a Win32 application (without MFC). When I pressed **F5** to debug my application, a new .exe file was produced under the **Release** folder rather than the Debug folder, because the **project configuration** in the current **active solution configuration**(which was **Debug**) was **Release** for some reason.

I was wondering why the .exe under **Release** folder, which seemed to be of a smaller size than the one under the **Debug** folder, could also be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

**Debug** and **Release** are just a configuration names and a debugger knows nothing about which one is intended for debugging purposes right now.

Internally they are equal. The default property values is the only difference. You can easily swap them manually in order to debug optimized code, for example.

Answer (score 0):

1) In **Debug mode** there are no optimizations performed by the compiler, while in **Release mode** there are optimizations. In release mode compiler performs some low-level changes to the code ,so that some pieces of code gets modified to achieve optimization.
2)In debug mode we have few settings enabled by default with help in generation of  debug symbols and files related to it like Map file, PDB  etc .These files are essential in debugging a crash dump .